# Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on

Tags: browser, cookies

I am currently working in existing project to upgrade it. The problem is when i click a link in the form i got an error "Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on". Could anyone help me out from this problem. This project is done by using PHP and MYSQL

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should follow the instructions given by the error?

Comment: are you trying to modify the form to not need cookies, or are you trying to figure out how to turn on cookies in your browser?

Comment: I think he asks how to turn cookies on

Comment: u r right Svetlozar Angelov.. I did it in the browser. But the error is not solved...

Comment: i am trying to turn on cookies in my browser. atk

Comment: Give us more information: What browser, what OS, what kind of cookie (session or persistent; first party or third party)?

Comment: I am assuming cookies on his computer work as he appears to be able to log in here to post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to turn the cookies in your browser on. What browser are you using? In FF, go to Tools > Options > Privacy. You can configure your settings there. In IE go to Tools > Internet Options > Privacy and set your security level to allow the cookies you want. Probably you'll have to lower your security level as well, but then again, IE was never the safest browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the "cookie functionality disabled" error before on Gmail too, despite having cookies enabled. In the end it just went away without any real reason why it had come up in the first place at all.

If you're using Chrome as your browser, you can configure your cookie settings by going to the wrench icon, then selecting Options, the `Under The Hood` tab, and then scrolling down to Cookie Settings (at the bottom of the Privacy section). For best compatibility with web page, you should set it to `Allow All Cookies`.

You can try setting it to `Restrict ...` if you have security concerns - most sites *should* still work okay, but if they have issues you might need to change the setting to `Allow All Cookies`.